# Асинхронная отправка email

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp

Я хочу отправить асинхронно письмо на разные **email адреса**, без задержек или же с задержками но допустим 2 одновременно. Можно ли это как-то решить? Или же нет?

**Пользуюсь yagmail так как там не нужно определять** `smtp.server`

Comment: Отправляйте в отдельном потоке.

Comment: Что значит "одновременно" ? Какова цель? Вы хотите, чтобы время отправки двух писем было секунда в секунду, или же время доставки секунда в секунду?

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik отправка в одно и  то же время

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev gevent, threads или smtp.send() и так по раз 100 ?

Comment: Создать один thread, в нём цикл, в цикле отправку.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev while True: thread = threading.Thread(target=send) ?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev могли бы вы добавить это в ответ?

Comment: Multiprocessing pool imap с несортированным вариантом. Зальёт письмами, асинхронности  не нужно

Answer (score 1):

Отправляйте в отдельном [потоке](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects):

```
from threading import Thread
from smtplib import SMTPException
import logging
import yagmail

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def send_mail(recipients, subject, content):
    yag = yagmail.SMTP()
    for recipient in recipients:
        try:
            yag.send(recipient, subject, content)
        except SMTPException as e:
            logger.warn(u'Не удалось отправить письмо получателю {} из-за ошибки: {}'.format(recipient, e.strerror))

recipients = ['someuser@example.com', 'anotheruser@example.com']
Thread(target=send_mail, args=(recipients, 'Not spam', 'Hello!')).start()
```

Comment: Emailaddress y is not valid according to RFC 2822, и так до самого моего email получателя.

Comment: И как мне кажется все равно та же скорость

Comment: Я поменял значение на recepients

Comment: Скорость не станет выше, это невозможно, так как лимитируется не python-кодом, а расторопностью smtp-сервера. Использование для отправки дополнительного потока просто позволит не блокировать основной поток программы. Если это, например, основной поток web-приложения, то пользователь получит ответ сразу же, а отправка будет происходит в фоне ещё какое-то время.

Comment: а если попытаться одновременно послать по одному письму на несколько email адресов ?

Comment: Переложите медленную часть работы с потока в вашем коде на поток в smtp-сервере. Ваша программа завершится быстрее, но получат письма адресаты примерно через тот же промежуток времени. И в таком случае надо аккуратным, чтобы не засветить полный список получателей всем в рассылке.

Comment: Асинхронность как я понял для smtp это бесполезное занятие, но можно же как-то реализовать массовую отправку по типу "одновременной"?